# Filtering sequences in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to do something like regular expressions with MATLAB to filter things out?   Basically I'm looking for something that will let me take a vector like:

```
[1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 4 1 1]
```

and will return:

```
[3 3 3 3 4 4 4]
```

These are the uninterrupted sequences (where there's no interspersion).

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain the point you are trying to make about the output? Is it the fact the 3'd and 4's have no other digits in between?

Comment: What about the "1"s? There's a sequence of 2 and 3 "1"s too.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the 3's and 4's have no other digits in between.  You compare the first occurrence of a digit and its last occurrence and return the sequence is there aren't any other digits in between.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using regular expressions

Use MATLAB's built-in [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) function for regular expression matching. However, you have to convert the input array to a string first, and only then feed it to `regexp`:

```
C = regexp(sprintf('%d ', x), '(.+ )(\1)+', 'match')
```

Note that I separated the values with spaces so that `regexp` can match multiple digit numbers as well. Then convert the result back to a numerical array:

```
res = str2num([C{:}])
```

The dot (`.`) in the pattern string represents any character. To find sequences of certain digits only, specify them in brackets (`[]`). For instance, the pattern to find only sequences of 3 and 4 would be:

```
([34]+ )(\1)+
```

#### A simpler approach

You can filter out successively repeating values by checking the similarity between adjacent elements using `diff`:

```
res = x((diff([NaN; x(:)])' == 0) | (diff([x(:); NaN])' == 0))
```

Optionally, you can keep only certain values from the result, for example:

```
res(res == 3 | res == 4)
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't expect this to be doable in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
v=[1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 4 1 1];
vals=unique(v); % find all unique values in the vector

mask=[]; % mask of values to retain

for i=1:length(vals)
   indices=find(v==vals(i)); % find indices of each unique value

   % if the maximum difference between indices containing
   % a given value is 1, it is contiguous
   % --> add this value to the mask
   if max(indices(2:end)-indices(1:end-1))==1
       mask=[mask vals(i)];
   end
end

% filter out what's necessary
vproc=v(ismember(v,mask))
```

Result:

```
vproc =

     3     3     3     3     4     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be another approach, although a little bit too elaborated.

If you see the plot of your array, you want to retain its level sets (i.e. `a == const`) which are *topologically connected* (i.e. made by one piece).

Coherently, such level sets are exactly the ones corresponding to `a==3` and `a==4`.

Here is a possible implementation

```
a = [1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 4 1 1]

r = [];  % result
b = a;   % b will contain the union of the level sets not parsed yet
while ~isempty(b)

    m = a == b(1);  % m is the current level set

    connected = sum(diff([0 m 0]).^2) == 2;  % a condition for being a connected set:
                                             % the derivative must have 1 positive and 1
                                             % negative jump
    if connected == true   % if the level set is connected we add it to the result 
        r = [r a(m)];          
    end

    b = b(b~=b(1));

end
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to think about this a bit...  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you try something like

```
a = [1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 4 1 1]    %initial vector
b = a>=3   %apply filter condition

a = a(b)   %keep values that satisfy filter
```

a will output

```
a = [3 3 3 3 4 4 4]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was not to capture values larger than 3.

Comment: The OP didn't specify how he was filtering, and it was the obvious filter technique. Notice the comments saying you apply your filter condition there, whatever it may be, the method works... Hardly worth a downvote @MarcClaesen ...

Comment: @iKiar quote from OP "These are the uninterrupted sequences (*where there's no interspersion*).". The filter condition was specified.

Comment: Yet his desired output doesn't match his description... So there are two problems to solve. The one he says he wants, or the one he asks for with his desired output. I solved the latter

Comment: The output does not contradict the description.

Comment: ... agree to disagree then.